# Application finished with exit code 126

Tags: linux, qt, ubuntu, raspberry-pi, cross-platform

I want to execute a qt application from Ubuntu (ubuntu-17.04-desktop-amd64) to raspberry pi3 (Raspbian).
I add "Generic Linux Device" (Device test successfully).
But when I run application, I have this errors:

```
bash: /home/pi/Test: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
bash: /home/pi/Test: Success
Application finished with exit code 126
```

Comment: I think the Qt Embedded Kit for RPI is not configured correctly. Maybe [this article](https://medium.com/@amirmann/how-to-cross-compile-qt-for-raspberry-pi-3-on-linux-ubuntu-for-beginners-75acf2a078c) may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Clean your project and compil it again.